# Mongo export objectId when it is a subfield

Tags: regex, mongoexport

My mongo model is like:

```
var something = {
    something1: {
        somevalue: ''
    },
    something2: {

        anObjectId: x._id
    },
}
```

I do:

```
mongoexport --db mydb --collection mycoll -f something1.somevalue -q "     
{\"something2.anObjectId\":{\"regex\":\"^[0-9A-Z]{24}$\"}}" --csv --fieldFile fields.txt -
-out outputFile.csv
```

But I get 0 records. What is wrong with this query or what is the best way to retrieve the objectId in something2 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at docs for [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/) and try to alter query to

```
mongoexport --db mydb --collection mycoll -f something1.somevalue -q '{"something2.anObjectId":{$regex: "^[0-9A-Z]{24}$"}}' --csv --fieldFile fields.txt --out outputFile.csv
```

Comment: Hi Twil. Thanks for your reply. I tried this. Again, no records are filtered out :( suspect it is something to do with the quotes ?

Comment: Sure it is! Just removed quotes around `$regex` and it worked like a charm.